# Filter an array using a formula (without VBA)

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to filter an array using a single formula (without autofilter, VBA, or additional columns)?

For example, I have the following spreadsheet:

```
   A  | B     | C
 --------------------
1| ID | Class | Value
2| 1  | A     | V1
3| 1  | B     | V2
4| 2  | A     | V3
5| 3  | B     | V4
6| 3  | B     | V5
```

I want to use a subset of this array in VLOOKUP.  Namely, I only want to match against those rows where class is "B".  So I was hoping I could use something like the following

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, FILTER_FUNC(A:C, B="B"), 3, false)
```

where FILTER_FUNC is some type of function or expression that returns an array that only contains those rows that meet the condition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,IF(B1:B3="B",A1:C3,""),1,FALSE)
```

[`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D) to enter.

Comment: I chose this answer because its form most closely matches the example in my question in the way it uses an _array function_ to pre-filter the **table_array**. Furthermore, I was able to understand and adapt this solution immediately.  Unfortunately, it is unclear to me how it works, and the closest thing I can find to documentation is the mention of "Criteria Array" in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275165).  Care to explain your answer?

Comment: @Bago, I always avoid array formulas when I can, they get complicated quickly.  Glad you found your answer.

Comment: The inside nested If statement will return an array of arrays to use in the lookup. So if B1:B3="B" returns {false; true; true}, then the result of the if statement will be {""; B1:B3; C1:C3}. This is then passed to the vlookup function, which treats this array as a set of rows to look in. The blank rows will never match. The non-blank rows (present because they matched the second criteria) will be searched for the first criteria. When a match is found, the column specified is returned.

Comment: Pay attention to the note `[Ctrl+Shift+Enter]` about entering array formulas, otherwise Excel may throw an error or return incorrect results.

Comment: Hello, I am looking for a solution like this where I would only get back the values associated with group B. However, my formula array only returns 1 for all values (curly brackets in place). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This will do it if you only want the first "B" value, you can sub a cell address for "B" if you want to make it more generic.

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(TRUE,(B2:B6)="B",0)),1)
```

To use this based on two columns, just concatenate inside the match:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(TRUE,(A2:A6&B2:B6)=("3"&"B"),0)),1)
```

Comment: This is definitely an interesting answer.  I understand that the MATCH() gets the row number of the first row where class is 'B' and then it uses that as a row position in INDEX().  What if I want to add another condition on a different column?  For example, I want to get the first row where Class is 'B' and ID is '3'.  Given the updated example data, the desired result is 'V4'.

Comment: By the way, I agree with your comment, on @GSerg's answer, about array formulas being complex.  Also, it seems to be a bit slow in my application.

Comment: @Bago, Answer updated.  SUMPRODUCT works like an array function, so it's a little complex also.

Comment: check out how it's done in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCAXRLYr59E

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just trying to do a classic two-column lookup. http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/

Tons of solutions for this, most simple is probably the following (which doesn't require an array formula):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Lookup!A:A=Param!A1)*(Lookup!B:B=Param!B1)*(Lookup!C:C))
```

To translate your specific example, you would use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3=A2)*(B1:B3="B")*(C1:C3))
```

Comment: This answer gives some great alternatives.  However, the SUMPRODUCT example doesn't quite work using my sample data because column C is alphanumeric--which results in a #VALUE error.

Comment: Yes, that is the shortcoming of the sumproduct method :/

Comment: Also, the VLOOKUP and INDEX examples in the link are less attractive because I would like to achieve the solution in a single formula without adding columns.  I will edit my answer to reflect this preference.

Comment: Yeah it's a tradeoff, you're either having to resort to array formulas (which means you can't reference an entire column and have it adjust automatically to an increasing table size), or you're adding columns, or you're using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Today, in Office 365, Excel has so called 'array functions'.
The `filter` function does exactly what you want. No need to use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` anymore, a simple `enter` will suffice.

In Office 365, your problem would be simply solved by using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, FILTER(A2:C6, B2:B6="B"), 3, FALSE)
```