# Retrieve greatest value of a field, for a range of cells specified dynamically by another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, array-formulas

The following is a rough analogy of the data I have to work with:

```
|SKU|   |Master SKU|    |Weight|
 0000
 0001    0000            5.6
 0002    0000            2
 0003    0000            4
 0004
 0005    0004            1
 0006    0004            3
 0007    0004            0.5
```

In a new column called `Master's Greatest Weight`; I need a formula that, for each row that has no `Master SKU`, returns the greatest weight of each row that has a match for it's own `SKU` in the `Master SKU` field.

To put it simply, this is the desired result:

```
|SKU|   |Master SKU|    |Weight|    |Master's Greatest Weight|
 0000                                5.6
 0001    0000            5.6
 0002    0000            2
 0003    0000            4
 0004                                3
 0005    0004            1
 0006    0004            3
 0007    0004            0.5
```

I have a feeling that this [Filter an array using a formula (without VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497062/filter-an-array-using-a-formula-without-vba) question is relevant, but if it is I'm not sure how to adapt it to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Is the data always sorted so that the values of master SKU are always grouped? If so, there is an easier way. I assume there are variable number of entries per master SKU. If not there is a much easier way.

Comment: @BKay our data's a mess, so let's assume they might not be grouped. And yes, there could be any number of entries.
Another thing to note, not every entry that has no `Master SKU` value is actually a Master itself - but those have their own weight entered so is not a problem.

Regardless of this, @pnuts answer seems to work very well - but if you have reason to believe it will fall short somewhere (based upon what you asked) then please say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try in SKU `0000` row (assumed to be Row2) and copied down:

```
 =IF(B2<>"","",MAX(IF(B:B=A2,C:C)))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. I'd vote up if I had more rep.
One thing though, while it works I'm not sure exactly how it does so - would you offer an explanation?