# Data Validation List filtered by row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example of the data:

```
  A      B
Item 1  TRUE
Item 2  FALSE
Item 3  TRUE
Item 4  FALSE
```

I want to create Data Validation list using formulas ONLY (no macros) that will return only items from column A that have TRUE in column B. In this example the List would contain Item 1 an Item 3. I tried the following formulas for the list (based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497062/filter-an-array-using-a-formula-without-vba)) with no luck.

Excel complains that The Source currently evaluates to an error with this formula:

```
=IF(B1:B4=TRUE,A1:A4,"")
```

This causes no errors but the returned list only contains Item 1:

```
=INDEX(A1:A4,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(TRUE,(B1:B4)=TRUE,0)),1)
```

Should be something very simple, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1,1,"")
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2,1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

and copy down.  In **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0)),"")
```

and copy down.

[image]

Then use column **D** for your *DV* list.

Comment: This works, but now my DV list also contains blank values if I use the hole column D for source. I can hard code the list to D1:D2, but I would like to be flexible…

Comment: create a dynamic range and use the range to drive the validation list

Comment: By dynamic range, I mean put this as the formula for the data validation source "=OFFSET($D$1,0,0,COUNTA($D:$D),1)"

Comment: @smackenzie  Thank you.

Comment: it probably needs some work, but you get the idea, CountA counts the formulae though and doesn't consider the cells blanks...just trying to suggest you look at formulae which return ranges such as Offset

Comment: In fact "COUNTIFS" works better:  =OFFSET($D$1,0,0,COUNTIFS($D:$D,"?*"),1).  The "?*" criteria means that there must be 1 character at least in the cell, so it ignores formulas which return nothing.

Comment: @smackenzie your last suggestion combined with the original Gary's Student solution works for me, thanks! I can't believe it needs to be so complicated for such a simple task as row filtering.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I think it's better to use `ROW()` instead of `1` for C1 column. If the table doesn't start at row 1, e.g. table starts at row 3 then C3 would be `=IF(B3,ROW(),"")`

Comment: @Ross  **Good Point**  I usually use `ROWS($1:1)` to make the starting row arbitrary!